# Android - "setToolbarColor(int)" and "setSecondaryToolbarColor(int)" is deprecated

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-intent, chrome-custom-tabs

I use this code to open links with Chrome Custom Tabs. But it's showing `@Deprecated` for `setToolbarColor()` and `setSecondaryToolbarColor()`. I haven't found anything for replacement.

Note: Android studio suggests "Use setDefaultColorSchemeParams instead." but haven't found any examples of that.

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.background));
        intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.background));
        intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(activity,R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
        intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(activity,android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity,uri);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `CustomTabColorSchemeParams` instead: [**Reference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabColorSchemeParams)

```java
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabColorSchemeParams params = new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
    .setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.background))
    .setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.background))
    .setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.background))
    .build();
intentBuilder.setColorSchemeParams(CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK, params);
intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(activity, R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(activity,android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity,uri);
```

Comment: Also add `.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.background))` to `params` and set `intentBuilder.setColorScheme(CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK)`.

Comment: @CoolMind Thanks. I edited my answer to support `setToolbarColor`.

Comment: Have you checked the answer without `intentBuilder.setColorScheme(CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK)` or default one? In my case it draws white Toolbar.

Comment: @CoolMind `CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK` doesn't work for me and it causes crash.

Comment: @Arghadip, that's strange. On emulator or device (what device) with what exception? In my case it doesn't work with COLOR_SCHEME_SYSTEM.

Comment: @CoolMind It was Pixel 2XL [api 30] emulator. I don't remember the exception.

Comment: @Arghadip, I tested on Nexus 5 (API 30) emulator and device. I think we should test these cases on devices. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295936/cant-change-chrome-custom-tabs-navigation-bar-color-when-running-in-the-android/61297124. Could you try `.setDefaultColorSchemeParams(params)` instead?

Comment: Instead of setColorSchemeParams(CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK, params) you should try with setDefaultColorSchemeParams(params)